# Upgrading Gradle Quarkus Plugin to 2.10.0.Final

Tags: gradle, quarkus

trying to upgrade Gradle's Quarkus Plugin to 2.10.0.Final. Running

```
./gradlew build -x test
```

leads to

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.quarkus', version: '2.10.0.Final']
> Failed to apply plugin 'io.quarkus'.
   > class org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProvider cannot be cast to class org.gradle.api.internal.provider.CollectionProviderInternal (org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProvider and org.gradle.api.internal.provider.CollectionProviderInternal are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @685cb137)
```

Above Exception gives me the impression, that `gradle` can't find version `2.10.0.Final` of the plugin, which is counter-intuitive for me ... it is available online https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.quarkus.

For reference:

gradle.properties

```
quarkusPluginVersion=2.10.0.Final
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-bom
quarkusPluginId=io.quarkus
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus.platform
quarkusPlatformVersion=2.10.0.Final
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    plugins {
        id "${quarkusPluginId}" version "${quarkusPluginVersion}"
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-12-22 12:37:54 UTC
Revision:     6f556c80f945dc54b50e0be633da6c62dbe8dc71

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.15 (Azul Systems, Inc. 11.0.15+10-LTS)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.1 x86_64
```

Comment: Sounds more like that version of Quarkus isn't compatible with the version of Gradle. What are you using?

Comment: I use Gradle 7.3.3. Will upgrade to 7.4.x

Comment: @BjørnVester You were right after upgrading to 7.4.2 builds are successful.